# react-leaflet error when quickly mounting and unmounting map

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I notice that when very quickly mount and unmount my leaflet map I run into the following error:

```
TypeError: el is undefined

  244 |     // this method is only used for elements previously positioned using setPosition,
  245 |     // so it's safe to cache the position for performance
  246 | 
> 247 |     return el._leaflet_pos || new Point(0, 0);
  248 | }
  249 | 
  250 | // @function disableTextSelection()
```

My code looks as follows

```
const MapComponent = ({ locations }) => {
  const map = useMap();

  const centerAroundMarkers = useCallback(() => {
    if (locations?.length > 0) {
      const bounds = L.latLngBounds();

      locations?.forEach((location) => {
        bounds.extend(L.latLng([location.y, location.x]));
      });
      map.fitBounds(bounds.pad(0.15));
    }
  }, [locations, map]);

  useEffect(() => {
    centerAroundMarkers();
  }, [centerAroundMarkers]);

  const viewerResize = useCallback(
    () =>
      debounce(() => {
        map.invalidateSize();
        centerAroundMarkers();
      }, 100),
    [centerAroundMarkers, map]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(viewerResize);
    resizeObserver.observe(map._container);

    return () => {
      console.log('unmount');
      console.log(map);
      resizeObserver.unobserve(map._container);
    };
  }, [viewerResize, map]);

  return null;
};


const HostsMap = ({ locations }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
      <MapContainer
        className={classes.mapContainer}
        dragging={false}
        bounds={[
          [-80, -160],
          [80, 160],
        ]}
        maxZoom={25}
        zoomControl={false}
        scrollWheelZoom={false}
        doubleClickZoom={false}
        boxZoom={false}
        touchZoom={false}
        keyboard={false}
        touchExtend={false}
        tap={false}
        zoomSnap={0.1}
      >
        <MapComponent locations={locations} />
        <>
          <TileLayer
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            maxNativeZoom={18}
            maxZoom={25}
            noWrap={false}
          />
        </>
      </MapContainer>
  );
};
```

Since the error is triggered when mounting and unmounting rather fast I suppose I'm not cleaning something up or that the cleaning takes too long and I'm already back before it is cleaned. The resizeObserver is suspect, but I do not see what I would not be cleaning up here.

Answer (score 0):

This is a super strange tactic to refit the map to the given markers.  You're better off using a `map.on('moveend')` event:

```
import { useMapEvents } from "react-leaflet";

const MapComponent = ({ locations }) => {
    const map = useMapEvents({
        moveend: () => {
            const bounds = L.latLngBounds();

            locations.forEach(location => {
                bounds.extend(L.latLng([location.y, location.x]));
            });

            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        },
    });

    return null;
};
```